# Python code that replaces \t\t failing to replace \t\r

Tags: python, csv

I always have replaced \t\t with \t999999999\t by coding like

```
for line in fileinput.input(input, inplace = 1):
    print line.replace('\t\t', '\t999999999\t'),
```

So I thought coding like the following will work for replacing \t\r with \t999999999\r

```
for line in fileinput.input(input, inplace = 1):
    print line.replace('\t\r', '\t999999999\r'),
```

But surprisingly it doesn't.

The input is tab-delimited txt.

Is \r something special that it can't be replaced in usual way? Then how can I replace it by python?

===Question edited====

I tried this.

```
for line in fileinput.input(input, inplace = 1):
    print line.replace('\t\n', '\t999999999\n'),
```

It works!

My input was separating lines by \r\n

Perhaps Python reads \r\n just as \n ?

Perhaps that's why it worked?

Does this code work if input separates lines by \r only?

Comment: `\r` is a line separator (usually in a combination with `\n`); Python most likely *replaced* it with `\n`.

Answer (score 3):

`\r` is (part of) a line separator. Python normalises line separators when reading files in text mode, using only `\n` for lines; `\r` and `\r\n` are replaced by `\n` when reading.

Note: When using `fileinput` you need to *strip* the newline from `line` otherwise you end up with *double* newlines in your output, rather than use `print ..,`:

```
for line in fileinput.input(input, inplace = 1):
    line = line.replace('\t\n', '\t999999999\n')
    print line.rstrip('\n')
```

`print ..,` adds an extra space to all your lines.

Comment: @Martjin_Pieters Thank you! I could solve the problem. But I solve the problem just by trying \n rather than \r.  I edited my question. Does that code in my edited question work if input separates lines by \r only?

Comment: @user3123767: exactly, `\r\n` (Windows line separator convention) is replaced by `\n` on read, and vice versa on write.

Comment: @Martjin_Pieters Is \r replaced by \n by python on read, too?